Value relation defaults to form's first value
I'm still learning QGis and I stumbled on an issue for which i can't find a solution in existing ressources online.
I'm currently working on a layer on which I'm mapping fruit tree plantations. There are 4 fruit species and up to 20+ varieties per species.
I wanted to use the relational value so that the form only shows the relevant varieties once the species is selected.
I prepared the Qgis project on my laptop at the office, then transferred the project via OneDrive to a tablet. This worked perfectly at the office (the selected variety remained on both the laptop and the tablet), but after testing in the field, the following problem appeared: the selected variety is always replaced by the first value in the list when I validate the form. If I try to replace the value in the attribute table afterwards, it reverts to the first value in the list as soon as I leave the line.
The problem is now also present on the laptop and I can't find a solution.
I found a post that talks about a similar problem, but the answer given (not validated) is obscure, and I don't think it applies to my problem. Here it is anyway :  Value Relation in QGIS keeps defaulting to the first value in the list no matter what pull down value I select
I've attached screenshots of the attribute form settings for the field concerned, and a ss of the CSV table (first couple lines) used to map the relation value, altough i don't think the issue comes form the CSV because it worked perfectly fine and wasn't edited since the problem appeared.




I found a better Question and a better Answer about my problem!
Value relation widget in QGIS
This one is far more useful as it details all CSV tables and the point of each field and setting.
My problem was that the Key column chosen in the Relation Value widget must have unique values, or the widget will display the first value of those that have the same Key.
I was using the Code column, with a Code for each species (=Essence in french) and a line for each variety within this species, so multiple lines with the same code.
Actually, i can simply use my variety column (=Variétés) as the Key AND the Value column, as each variety is a unique value.
Last step is to rewrite the filter expression to make the form display only Varieties for which the 'Essence' column's value matches the "Essence" field of the current feature:

"Essence" = current_value('Essence')

Hope this will help the next ones who will stumble on the problem. If that's your case, go check the original Question linked above, it's far much clearer than mine.
